# Pandas: Split cell into multiple colums, write NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['root:catA', 'root:catA:catB'], 'Age':[32, 34]})
```

Now I want to split the column `Category` by `:` into, in total 4, columns. Since there will be less columns because row0 has will result in 4 filled columns, row1 in 5 filled columns, the rest of the columns should be filled with `NaN`.

Expected output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['root:catA', 'root:catA:catB'], 'Age':[32, 34], 'Cat1':['root', 'root'], 'Cat2':['catA', 'catA'], 'Cat3':['NaN', 'CatB'], 'Cat4':['NaN', 'NaN']})
```

I tried the following:

```
df[['cat1','cat2', "cat3", "cat4"]] = df.Category.str.split(":",expand=True)
```

But I am getting a 
`ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost there, you just needed an additional reindex step:

```
df['Category'].str.split(':', expand=True).reindex(range(4), axis=1)                                                   

      0     1     2   3
0  root  catA  None NaN
1  root  catA  catB NaN
```

Now, assigning will work.

Alternatively, `join` them together.

```
(df['Category'].str.split(':', expand=True)
               .reindex(range(4), axis=1)
               .rename(lambda x: f'cat{x+1}', axis=1)
               .join(df))

   cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4        Category  Age
0  root  catA  None   NaN       root:catA   32
1  root  catA  catB   NaN  root:catA:catB   34
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expand only gives 3 columns, you need to remove `Cat4` and assign later:

```
df[['cat1','cat2', "cat3"]] = df.Category.str.split(':', expand=True)
df['cat4'] = np.nan
```

Comment: the idea is that I can add split a cell without caring if the number of rows is more than the three I can have in the example